# Logstash - Basic Grok Pattern not working

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am completely new to Logstash. I just started working on it today. I did not find any good tutorials. So I am posting my query here.

## I have a basic conf file:

```
 input {
    file{
        path => "C:/software/logstash-5.3.0/logstash-5.3.0/bin/test1.txt"
        type => "Text File"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {

    grok { 
        match => [ "message", "%{WORD:File Name} %{WORD:Method Name} %{NUMBER:testing Number} %{NUMBER:testing second number}" ] 
    } 
}

output{

    file {
        path => "C:/software/logstash-5.3.0/logstash-5.3.0/bin/test_op1.txt"
        codec => line  { format => "File Name is: %{File Name} and Method Name is: %{Method Name}"
        }    
    }

    stdout {}
}
```

I made this conf file by seeing few examples in the google search.

My Input File contains just one line: testFile testMethod 123 345

I am just trying to understand how Logstash works here.

I ran the logstash using the above conf file and input file.
It started running successfully.
And "testFile testMethod 123 345" got printed on the Console.
And "File Name is: %{File Name} and Method Name is: %{Method Name}
" got printed to the Output File.
Whereas, Expected output is: "File Name is: testFile and Method Name is: testMethod"

After adding codec=>rubydebug to the output of the config file, output is attached as an image.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDPfu.jpg)

Could you please suggest me where I was wrong.
Do I need to create any pattern file or Is there any default pattern file for grok.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on this [elastic.co support thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/discover-field-names-with-spaces/37467/4), I would discourage the use of spaces and inconsistent capitalization strategies in your field names

Comment: Please run this with `stdout{codec => "rubydebug"}` and add the results to your question

Comment: Added the results as an image to the question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Issue is because of the spaces used. I removed the spaces and it is working now. Thanks a lot @will

Answer (score 2):

Identified the issue. Issue is caused by the Naming Conventions I used in the GROK pattern. Using Spaces in the GROK pattern caused the issue.

## Corrected Grok Pattern

```
grok { 
    match => [ "message", "%{WORD:FileName} %{WORD:MethodName} %{NUMBER:Number1} %{NUMBER:Number2}" ] 
}
```

By using this GROK pattern, my issue is resolved.
Thanks for the suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/users/5216668/will-barnwell